# Bootstrap: Create images on same row

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I want to create a list item in a game that has a background, an iconholder with an icon inside it, a title and description and up to three resources. I am working with Bootstrap and thought that using a container-fluid with a row inside it might work but the images are placed underneath each other (see image) [[image: this is what I have right now.]]

I don't want to use things like position:absolute, or set the margin at like -250% 0 0 0. Is there a way to say that images should be placed on top of one another, instead of underneath each other?

This is my HTML code thus far:

```css
.resourceHolder
{
 position: relative;
}

.resourceIcon
{
 position: relative;
}

.nopadding 
{
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

.iconHolder
{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

.icon
{
 position: relative;
    width: 65%;
}

.bannerText
{
    font-family: FenwickWood;
    color: #0062cc;
 margin: 0 0 20% 0;
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: beige;

    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <img class="background" src="assets/UI/window/wood_plank1.svg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
  <img class="iconHolder" src="assets/UI/window/grid4L.svg">
  <img class="icon" src="assets/Terrain_Medieval/Decor/villageSmall03.png">
    </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
  <h1 class="bannerText">Village</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
  <img class="resourceHolder" src="assets/UI/window/grid4L.svg">
  <img class="resourceIcon" src="assets/Icons/gold_coins.png">
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you can do a stackblitz program that we can help you , or post the images used that i can do one for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS Grid layout, and put both images in the same cell.

Checkout out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dscmr7oz/.

Also, when you say you don't want to use things like position:absolute", why is that?  It is a completely legitimate way to put things on top of each other.  Are you aware that if you put an absolute-positioned element inside a relative-positioned element, that the inner element is absolutely positioned, relative to its parent?

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.container .bottom-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
{

.container .top-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2
}
```

Comment: yes, that's what I was looking for :)
I forgot to add a parent and tbh i thought adding position:absolute was sort of 'cheating' to get good results at first that get completely wrong once you add multiple elements under each other